# STRING_AGG with CASE WHEN

Tags: sql-server, string-agg

**The schema**

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
     [first_name] VARCHAR(10), 
     [surname] VARCHAR(10), 
     [dob] DATE, 
     [person_id] INT
);

INSERT INTO person ([first_name], [surname], [dob] ,[person_id]) 
VALUES
    ('Alice', 'AA', '1/1/1960', 1),
    ('Bob'  , 'AA', '1/1/1980', 2),
    ('Carol', 'AA', '1/1/2018', 3),
    ('Dave' , 'BB', '1/1/1960', 4),
    ('Elsa', ' BB', '1/1/1980', 5),
    ('Fred' , 'BB', '1/1/1990', 6),
    ('Gina' , 'BB', '1/1/2018', 7);

CREATE TABLE person_membership
(
    [person_id] INT, 
    [personstatus] VARCHAR(1), 
    [membership_id] INT, 
    [relationship] INT
);

INSERT INTO person_membership ([person_id], [personstatus], [membership_id], [relationship])
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 10, 1),
    (2, 'A', 10, 2),
    (3, 'A', 10, 3),
    (4, 'A', 20, 1),
    (5, 'A', 20, 2),
    (6, 'A', 20, 4),
    (7, 'A', 20, 5);
```

In this simplified scheme the person with relationship set to 1 one is the main policy holder while different numbers show how other people are related to the main policy holder (spouse, children etc.)

**The problem**

Show all dependants for each main policy holder and group them within arbitrarily chosen age groups.

The desired output:

```
person_id|membership_id|first_name|dependants under 10|dependants over 10
---------+-------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------
       1 |          10 |   Alice  |               Bob |            Carol
       4 |          20 |    Dave  |              Gina |       Elsa, Fred
       8 |          30 |   Helen  |     Ida, Joe, Ken |             NULL
```

My efforts so far:

```
SELECT 
    sub.person_id, sub.membership_id, sub.first_name, 
    STRING_AGG (sub.dependant, ',')
FROM
    (SELECT 
         person.person_id, person_membership.membership_id, 
         person.first_name, p.first_name AS 'dependant', 
         DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, p.dob), GETDATE()) AS 'age'
     FROM   
         person
     LEFT JOIN 
         person_membership ON person.person_id = person_membership.person_id
     LEFT JOIN 
         memship  ON person_membership.membership_id = memship.membership_id
     LEFT JOIN 
         person_membership pm ON person_membership.membership_id = pm.membership_id AND pm.relationship > 1
     LEFT JOIN 
         person p ON pm.person_id = p.person_id
     WHERE 
         person_membership.relationship = 1) as sub
GROUP BY 
    sub.person_id, sub.membership_id, sub.first_name
```

I can't figure out how to use `CASE WHEN` with `STRING_AGG`.

When I try something like

```
"CASE WHEN age < 10 THEN STRING_AGG (sub.dependant, ',') ELSE NULL END as 'Under 10'"
```

the server rightly protests that

> contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

but of course grouping by it doesn't solve the problem either so there is a trick that I am missing.  Also I'm sure it's possible to write the main query itself in a simpler way.

**Edit - solution**

As @Gserg rightly pointed out, and what I have realised moments after posting the question, the solution is very simple and calls for using CASE WHEN within STRING_AGG and not the other way around.  Doh.

```
string_agg(case when age < 10 then sub.dependant else null end, ', ') as 'Under 10'
```

Still still looking for suggestions and ideas how to improve on my original query.

Comment: Inverse it. `string_agg(case when age < 10 then sub.dependant else null end)`.

Comment: @GSerg - thanks, so obvious.  Stumbled onto this obviousness about 10 seconds after posting the question.

Answer (score 5):

maximize using the `iif` function for a single condition.

```
SELECT sub.person_id, sub.membership_id, sub.first_name, 
    STRING_AGG (iif(age < 10, sub.dependant, null), ',') 'Under 10'
FROM   (SELECT person.person_id, person_membership.membership_id, person.first_name, p.first_name AS 'dependant', 
        DATEDIFF(yy,CONVERT(DATETIME, p.dob),GETDATE()) AS 'age'

        FROM   person

        LEFT JOIN person_membership ON person.person_id = person_membership.person_id
        LEFT JOIN person_membership  memship  ON person_membership.membership_id = memship.membership_id
        LEFT JOIN person_membership pm ON person_membership.membership_id = pm.membership_id AND pm.relationship > 1
        LEFT JOIN person p             ON pm.person_id = p.person_id
        WHERE person_membership.relationship = 1) as sub
GROUP BY sub.person_id, sub.membership_id, sub.first_name
```

Comment: Note - in Snowflake it isn't `IIF`, it is `IFF`